# TinyMCE in Joomla 4: <custom-element> without automatically added <p>

Tags: joomla, tinymce, custom-element, paragraph

Can someone please tell me how it becomes possible in TinyMCE that a custom HTML element e.g.

`<my-custom-element>text...</my-custom-element>`

when saving the article is NOT always forcibly converted to

`<p><my-custom-element>text...</my-custom-element></p>`,

but remains without the added `<p>... </p>`

like it is when I use e.g. `<blockquote>`?

Otherwise `<p>` should remain the default for new paragraphs if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a TinyMCE bug/missing feature: https://www.tiny.cloud/contact/

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is a really frustrating Tinymce thing that has been there forever.  You could potentially write a plugin to modify the text before save.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE can certainly do this via the `custom_elements` options as shown here:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/oWhaab

Adding

```
custom_elements : 'mycustomblock'
```

...to the TinyMCE configuration is how you do this.

I have no idea how you would add this configuration to Joomla but assuming you can do so TinyMCE itself can certainly support this desired behavior.